# Malicious code in Order Address

Tags: magento2, orders

I got many orders in which I found malicious code in the order address section. My website's Magento version is 2.4.5-p1. I am afraid it is some kind of malware attack and if it is so please suggest some solutions for this problem as soon as possible. Please check the attached order image.

[image: Malicious code image]

Comment: Please go to Magento Admin configuration -> Customer -> customer configuration -> Address template  here check the template there should be some tag missing which is causing the issue. try below link for reference https://bsscommerce.com/blog/Magento-2-change-customer-address-templates-Magento+2 . This might help you

Comment: This issue is not for all orders. When I make some research on the internet I found there is Trojan Orders Attack on my website. https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/security/magento-stores-targeted-in-massive-surge-of-trojanorders-attacks/